# Length of video created with PyAV

Tags: python, video, computer-vision, bitrate, pyav

When creating a video from a list of frames at an assigned framerate using PyAV, the videos end up being shorter that expected by a few seconds, while the framerate in the video metadata is correct.
Here is a sample code of the function to save the videos:

```
def save_video(video_name,imlist,framerate,bitrate):
    container = av.open(video_name, mode='w')
    stream = container.add_stream('h264', framerate)
    stream.codec_context.bit_rate = bitrate*1e3 # Bitrate in kbps
    stream.width = image_width
    stream.height = image_height    
    stream.pix_fmt = 'yuv420p'
    for image in imlist:
            image = av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(image)
            packet = stream.encode(image)
            container.mux(packet)
    container.close()
```

For example, when making a video from 600 frames at 30fps, the result is an 18s video instead of 20s. Loading the video again, it looks like some frames were dropped.

I would like to stick with PyAV as I can easily set the bitrate. I have tried using OpenCV, which works but produces very large video files.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to flush the remaining packets from encoder before closing the container.

Flushing the encoder is done by encoding `None` and muxing the output packets.
Add the following code before `container.close()`:

```
remain_packets = stream.encode(None)
container.mux(remain_packets)
```

---

Code sample for testing:

```
import av
import numpy as np
import cv2

def save_video(video_name, imlist, framerate, bitrate):
    image_height, image_width, ch = imlist[0].shape
    container = av.open(video_name, mode='w')
    stream = container.add_stream('h264', framerate)
    stream.codec_context.bit_rate = bitrate*1e3 # Bitrate in kbps
    stream.width = image_width
    stream.height = image_height
    stream.pix_fmt = 'yuv420p'
    for image in imlist:
        image = av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(image)
        packet = stream.encode(image)
        container.mux(packet)

    # Flush the encoder
    remain_packets = stream.encode(None)
    container.mux(remain_packets)

    container.close()


def make_sample_image(i, width, height):
    """ Build synthetic "raw RGB" image for testing """
    p = width//60
    img = np.full((height, width, 3), 60, np.uint8)
    cv2.putText(img, str(i+1), (width//2-p*10*len(str(i+1)), height//2+p*10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX, p, (30, 30, 255), p*2)  # Blue number (going to be blue when treated as RGB instead of BGR).
    return img


# Build a list of 100 images with sequential frame counter for testing:
imlist = []
for n in range(100):
    img = make_sample_image(n, 192, 108)
    imlist.append(img)

save_video("output_vid.mp4", imlist, 1, 1000)
```