# Python Av encode result is empty always

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, pyav

I'm quite a newbie when it comes to ffmpeg and av, I was trying to do a simple encode - decode example but the encode result always returns an empty list. I don't understand the reason for this, I don't know how it can be solved.

```
import av
import numpy as np
import cv2 

container = av.open(file = "video=PC Camera",format = "dshow",options = {"video_size":"640x480"},mode = "r")

def getFrame():
    # open camera
    for frame in container.decode(video=0):
        yield frame
        
def encode(frame):
    encoder = av.CodecContext.create('h264', 'w')
    encoder.width = frame.width
    encoder.height = frame.height
    encoder.pix_fmt = frame.format.name
    encoder.bit_rate = 5000000
    encoder.framerate = 30
    encoder.open()
    frames = encoder.encode(frame)
    encoder.close()
    return frames
    
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while 1:
        frame = next(getFrame())
        frame_encoded = encode(frame)
        print(frame_encoded) // always empty
        if len(frame_encoded) == 0:
            continue
        #cv2.imshow("frame",frame.to_ndarray(format = "bgr24"))
        #cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Comment: I haven't used this library before, but I think encoding each frame into a separate h264 video can't possibly work. If nothing else, encoding them into separate videos is going to have terrible compression - video compression relies on compressing differences between frames.

Comment: Take a look at my [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76133349/4926757). Replace `for image in imlist` with `image = next(getFrame())`, and make some adjustments. In general, we don't suppose to create and close the encoder for each frame. Please explain your goal. Are you trying to encode the frames from the camera to a list of encoded frames in memory?

Comment: Thank you for your answers, actually I was just trying to learn. I actually thought that the encoder.open and encoder.close methods were like a lock system, I was opening them for each encoding and then closing them, but this was an unnecessary and wrong operation. The main reason why it constantly returned an empty list was that I was constantly recreating the encoder. Unfortunately, it escaped my attention, thank you again.

Comment: Maybe the library has some examples on how to decode/encode a video. In general terms I'd say an encoder is created/opened, then in a loop it processes the data, then after the loop it closes/destroys. Try this approach and see if some `frame_encoded`s are not empty.

Comment: @mortalis Exactly as you said, the shutdown should be done after the loop, as I was a novice, I was performing the shutdown after each encode & decode operation. Thank you very much for your answer.