# Why does the PyAV-encoded video have a different total time in seconds than the original file

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg, pyav

I'm taking a mp4 file, decoding it frame by frame and reencoding it. I'm using PyAV and the reencoding is running on h265.
When the code is running, it seems that all frames are passed from the decoder to the encoder, but at the end I have a file with 3 seconds less. For longer videos I'll have bigger differences.

I have already checked the fps, it comes out with a very small variation, even if I use the Fraction type to avoid decimal differences.

I'd like to know if it's some parametrization error, or if this is something to do with the encoder itself like keyframes and all those sort of things. Is there a way to fix it?

```
import av


container = av.open('input.mp4')

# create an output container to receive the transcoded video packets
output_container = av.open('output.mp4', 'w', format='mp4')
# add a stream to output container with same fps as input and h265 codec
output_stream = output_container.add_stream(
    'libx265', rate=container.streams.video[0].average_rate)
# set the output stream size
output_stream.width = 640
output_stream.height = 480

print('Starting transcoding...')

actual_frame = 0
container_total_frames = container.streams.video[0].frames

# start decoding packets and reading frames from the container
try:
    for packet_input in container.demux():
        if packet_input.dts is None:
            break
        for frame in packet_input.decode():

            try:
                actual_frame += 1
                # convert the frame to a numpy array
                img = frame.to_ndarray(format='bgr24')

                # prepare the ndarray frame and encode it
                frame_nd = av.VideoFrame.from_ndarray(img, format='bgr24')
                packet_output = output_stream.encode(frame_nd)
                output_container.mux(packet_output)
                print('Frame: {}/{}'.format(actual_frame, container_total_frames))
            except Exception as e:
                print("Error writing frame: ", e)
                break
except Exception as e:
    print('Finished transcoding')

output_container.close()

print('Finished transcoding')
```

Comment: where's the stream flushing? what can you claim about the timebases and PTSes? can you rely on the source having a fixed frame rate? if not, why do you trust the "average" rate? you need to provide input data to reproduce this issue. [mre]

Comment: As commended by @ChristophRackwitz, flushing is missing. Take a look at my [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76133349/4926757). After the loop add `remain_packets = output_stream.encode(None)` and `output_container.mux(remain_packets)`. For testing, you may provide a synthetic video generated by FFmpeg CLI: `ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i testsrc=s=192x108:r=25:d=5 input.mp4`. In case it's working with the synthetic video, and there is a gap with your input file, please share an input video file (share using Google Drive for example).

Comment: Thanks for the hints. As you guys pointed out, I did not flush the packets, actually, i did not know about it. It solved the problem for one of the videos. The second one, after some debugging seems to be a problem with the varying fps. That's the reason why I used the average rate. Anyways, when I create an output container, how am I supposed to write frames from a varying fps input? I'm trying to find a video with the same problem to share, since the one I have here is from my client's camera. Synthetic videos did not show this problem, probably due to the stable fps of the stream.

Comment: Is there a way to write the frames by using the timebase or pts from the original frame and not declaring the fps when declaring the output container?